# Can I get back to root-able HBoot version by doing a factory reset

Tags: rooting, bootloader, htc-wildfire, downgrade, unrevoked

I have a HTC Wildfire (Buzz) that originally came with Eclair. I now have Froyo on it and the Unrevoked tool doesn't work as the HBoot version is not supported (too new for Unrevoked).

At this point, I don't care about losing the data on the phone (they are backed up anyway). So, can I do a factory reset to get the old firmware back that can be rooted?

I'm ready to do anything to get Cyongenmod on this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, performing a factory reset won't affect your HBoot version.

You should, however, be able to follow [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1230934) instead (which uses [Revolutionary](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/revolutionary)). There's another page with instructions [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1029318) which describes in a bit more detail what Revolutionary does and where to go from there. The standard disclaimers with regards to possibly bricking your device apply, of course, and I can't guarantee 100% that it will work.

Comment: Doesn't seem like that'll work. As HBOOT 1.01.0001 is listed as a prerequisite. I have HBOOT 1.01.0002 which is why it didn't work with Unrevoked.

Comment: Second link you've listed has a how to link on downgrading HBOOT. Will give that a spin and post back :)

Comment: I manged to downgrade HBOOT to 1.01.1001. But Revolutionary and Unrevoked both still fail to turn S-OFF :(
Guess there's no hope..